# Configuring SpringBatch with Nosql

Tags: java, spring-batch, marklogic

We need to use spring batch in an application which already uses a `NoSQL` product (`MarkLogic`). I know that as a pre-requisite spring-batch uses some relational tables for infrastructure management and monitoring like batch status etc.

Does `spring-batch` provide a way via which we can configure it to work with `NoSQL` products like this?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch Job Repository is based on JDBC DAOs and support a close set of RDBM’s. For example in Spring Batch 2.2.5 its DB2, HSQL,  SQLSERVER,  MYSQL,  ORACLE, POSTGRES,SYBASE, H2. 
See org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType class from spring-batch-infrastructure-x.x.x.jar

As mentioned in Rafik Beldi answer Memory Based Job Repository is supported as well. Those can be a good solution if you do not care about past executions. In memory database like [h2](http://www.h2database.com/) support file based persistent that my help (although limited and unreliable from my point of view).

If you have to support NoSQL you need to develop your own or look for some existing project in github.
Basically starting by overriding JobRepositoryFactoryBean and adding your own DAOs (located under 
org.springframework.batch.core.repository package in spring-batch-core jar). 
For more information:

1. The [Spring Batch Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository) Non-standard Database Types in a Repository
2. Some [mongodb](http://blog.sadogursky.com/2010/04/27/integrating-mongodb-with-spring-batch/) project with Spring Batch
3. Maybe my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789731/using-redshfit-as-spring-batch-job-repository-and-alternatives-to-sequence-in-re) will add some information

It will be nice if someone from Spring Batch team will give us some information if NoSQL support for job repository are planed to the near feature.

Answer (score 0):

spring-batch may uses datasource but there are scenarios in which you may not want to persist your domain objects to the database. One reason may be speed; storing domain objects at each commit point takes extra time. Another reason may be that you just don't need to persist status for a particular job. For this reason, Spring batch provides an in-memory Map version of the job repository:

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/> </bean>
```

Comment: Not very useful because this approach can be used only for testing and fast prototyping as suggested by spring. [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html)